# Asymptotics of integer compositions

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

A (weak) composition of a positive integer $n$ into $k$ parts is an ordered sequence of nonnegative integers $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k)$ such that $ \sum_{i=1}^k a_i = n $. I am interested in the case when the parts are bounded: $a_i\in\{0, 1, \ldots, j-1\}$. The number of such compositions satisfies the two-variable recurrence
\begin{equation}
\kappa(n,j,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\kappa(n-i,j,k-1)
\end{equation}
and can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
\kappa(n,j,k) = \sum_{s\geq0} (-1)^s {k \choose s} {k-sj+n-1 \choose k-1}
\end{equation}
[R. P. Stanley, Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol. I, p. 307].
Does someone know how to work out the asymptotics of $\kappa(n,j,k)$ when $k\to\infty$, $n\sim\lambda k$, $\lambda\in(0,j-1)$, and $j$ is fixed?

Comment: Question posted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191510/diagonal-asymptotics-of-integer-compositions